# Use Elastic Beanstalk env variables in Docker file deployment

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible at the time my Docker file build in elastic beanstalk is executed to obtain the environment variables that were defined in the environment?

Example:

```
#env_name : Environment variable that is setup previously
RUN npm run $env_name
```

I have reviewed that currently EBS does not support passing variable to the build process, but I have seen a workaround run a prehook to take the variables to the container, but I cannot understand if that prehook should be called from the dockerfile or an initial configuration is needed.